# How to add rip-out pages exactly in the middle of a booklet?

Tags: xetex, pdf, printing

I am creating a staple-bound booklet for printing. I make sure it has a page count that is a multiple of 4. Now I have a few independent pages, also always a multiple of 4, that I would like to inject in the middle of the booklet.

Those middle pages should not interfere with the remaining layout - neither page count or any other layout of the main book (e.g. two-column layouts), and I would like to avoid to manually count pages and update the position every time the main content grows. This middle part might even be right in the middle of a chapter where one half of a sentence is before and the other half after the injected pages.

Rationale: this is a game rule booklet, and the middle pages are rip-out maps and game pieces, leaving the actual game booklet after they are removed.

Is there an easy way to do this within (Xe)LaTeX, or should I rather post-process the PDF and inject the pages afterwards?

Comment: are your insert pages just pdf or do you have tex source you could input?

Comment: The inserted pages would benefit if I also do them in LaTeX, as they contain text/labels/instructions for cutting/folding etc. But, depending on the effort of injecting this, I might set those in Inkscape.

Comment: @TeXter : This is easy with pdfpages.

Comment: @Werner: not sure if pdfpages can handle my case better than an external tool like `pdftk`. The benefit of doing this in LaTeX for me would be uniform handling of page layout (bleed/no-bleed for print/ebook versions) with the rest of the document.

Comment: With [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) you can decide "I want the next page to contain a tear-out page. With [`pdftk`](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) you would have to examine the document to see where the page should be inserted. I would think `pdfpages` is therefore be just as easy as the tear-outs occur "exactly in the middle" and therefore together. How are you printing your booklet format though?

Comment: The booklet is printed in large numbers (digital or offset - not yet sure) by a printing company, if that is what you ask. In case of pdfpages, how do I automate the find-middle-of-booklet and how does it postpone the main layout between page-before and page-after middle section? How about phrasing that as an answer?